# F1 score values different for F1 score metric and classification report sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, metrics

I am trying to analyze my results so i am using the F1 score metric and classification report on sklearn. The results displayed are totally different irrelevant of the type of averaging.
It does not match at all.
example on my validation data

F1 score 0.7666666666666667

But the classification report results are:

```
  report       precision recall  f1-score   support
       0       0.16      0.57      0.25         7
       1       0.40      0.09      0.14        23
accuracy                           0.20        30



macro avg      precision: 0.28, recall:0.33,  f1score:0.20      support:30

weighted avg       precision:0.34      recall:0.20      f1score:0.17        support:30
```

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks!

My code is:
` print('F1 score {}'.format(sklearn.metrics.f1_score(test_label, np.round(y_pred), average='micro'))´

And for classification report it is:

` print('F1 score {}'.format(sklearn.metrics.classification_report(test_label, np.round(y_pred), target_names=labels))´

labels is just a list with  my classlabels in it.

Comment: what is your concret question?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Sorry my question is why is there a difference in the F1 scores? and my code is updated.

Comment: Why use micro average? Your problem is a binary classification, you can go with the default value 'binary' as value for the average parameter. In this case the f1-score should be equal to the f1-score of the 1 case in the classification report

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the f1-score, you ask to scikit to compute the average='micro', but the classification report computes the macro and weighted average.

Try `print('F1 score {}'.format(sklearn.metrics.f1_score(test_label, np.round(y_pred), average='macro'))`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i already tried that but still the values do not match or its not even close.